# wp_get_current_user in custom file returns 0

Tags: user-meta

I need to access logged-in user data in a custom PHP file that I call in a WP page through an include.

The include file is:

```
require($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/wp-config.php'); 
require($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/wp-load.php'); 
$current_user = wp_get_current_user(); 
var_dump($current_user->ID);
var_dump($current_user->display_name);
```

And it outputs:
int(0) bool(false) int(0) bool(false)

However... In the very same page, I also call a function that I entered in function.php:

```
$current_user = wp_get_current_user();
var_dump($current_user->ID);
var_dump($current_user->display_name);
```

And this one outputs:
int(1) string(10) "antoine251"

It looks to me like WP functions called from my external php file are not working.

What am I missing?
(No pluggin is even installed, same results in twentynineteen theme than is my custom theme)

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: You try to get user data to early

Comment: Thanks Krzysiek, what I am I missing prior to getting user data? Sorry for my questions, but I'm totally lost!

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is that you want to get current user to early.

`wp_get_current_user` is using global `current_user` variable.

But this variable isn’t set from the beginning.

And if you want to use this function straight in the script file, then it’s to early.

You should wait for `init` action to get current user.

```
require($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/wp-config.php'); 
require($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/wp-load.php'); 

add_action( 'init', function() {
    $current_user = wp_get_current_user(); 
    var_dump($current_user->ID);
    var_dump($current_user->display_name);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for these details! But still can't have the user data

Comment: I sure will and I really appreciate your help, but that doesn't seem to work. I'll edit my question to show new results

Comment: can't have this to work, any precision would help. Thanks

Comment: I just realized something interesting: all user data are shown properly if I call the include-data.php file (where I use WP function to store user data as variables) directly in Chrome's address bar. However, when the very same include-data.php is called with a page, then user data are empty :-/